# What does it mean by singular limit?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

curruntly I'm working on some one dimensional system, in this paper http://www.bcamath.org/documentos_public/archivos/publicaciones/15.pdf
In this paper, the author have 
mentionned  'singular limit" and I have never heart about it, Can you give me some details or references ? thank you.

Comment: I found some examples by googling, but no clear definition.
https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/masmoudi/handbook.pdf
https://michaelberryphysics.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/berry341.pdf
It seems like it's used for limits that are in some way not well-behaved, e.g. there is not continuity.

Comment: When a system shows completely different behaviour in the limit of some parameter, the limit is called singular. Imagine a parameter k and that you want to study the behaviour of the system when k goes to infinity. You cannot say anything about the behaviour of the system at the infinite limit from the knowledge of its behaviour when k is finite.